# Extract by expression in Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, extract

I have tried several times to run “extract by expression” algorithm in Model Builder with the following expression, but system always crashes, maybe there is something wrong:

```
CASE 
WHEN @maximumnumberofbuildings <= minimum("id_count", group_by:= "id") THEN "id_count" = minimum("id_count", group_by:= "id") 
WHEN @maximumnumberofbuildings >= maximum("id_count", group_by:= "id") THEN "id_count" = maximum("id_count", group_by:= "id") 
WHEN (@maximumnumberofbuildings > minimum("id_count", group_by:= "id") AND @maximumnumberofbuildings <=median("id_count", group_by:= "id")) THEN "id_count"<= median("id_count", group_by:= "id") 
WHEN (@maximumnumberofbuildings < maximum("id_count", group_by:= "id") AND @maximumnumberofbuildings >=median("id_count", group_by:= "id")) THEN "id_count">= median("id_count", group_by:= "id") 
END
```

`maximumnumberofbuildings`, `id_count`, `id` are `integer64` type. I have tried also to run it from processing toolbox (with a number instead of `maximumnumberofbuildings`) but it works very slowly only with one `WHEN`, so an easier expression, but the output is a empty layer.

Operating system: Windows 10 version 1903
QGIS version: 3.10.6-A Coruña
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020

Comment: Please describe in your own words what you're trying to do here. Because to me it seems you're just pushing numbers around and not trying to meet any criteria for actual selection.

Comment: It's a selection of service areas of waste collection points. I want to select service areas (road segments) with a certain number of buildings releted, the problem is that this code it's ok on linux but not on windows

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Could you now break your code down to show, what which part should do?